# concrete class method not overrides abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart, abstract-class

Having abstract class with methods that should be defined in multiple concrete class. For simplicity sake, here is an example:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass extends StatelessWidget{

  const MyAbstractClass ({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(abstractMethod().toString());
  }
  
  int _abstractMethod();
}

class MyConcreteClass1 extends MyAbstractClass {
  @override
  int _abstractMethod() {
    return 42;
  }
}

class MyConcreteClass2 extends MyAbstractClass {
  @override
  int _abstractMethod() {
    return 66;
  }
}
```

now when I try to call MyConcreteClass1 or MyConcreteClass2 it gives me the error below:

> 'MyConcreteClass1' has no instance method '_abstractMethod'

How to call `MyConcreteClass1` or `MyConcreteClass2` within my screen?

**Note** that it will work if I called and instance of it like below:

```
MyConcreteClass1 c = MyConcreteClass1();
int value = c._abstractMethod();
```

but it should have been called by `build` method in abstract class, right?

Comment: This is behaving as you're expecting for me. See [here](https://dartpad.dev/f736999bee4a3a8a703af101191bf41d).

Comment: I know it should work, right? but this is strange because even the delaration of `abstractMethod` in `MyConcreteClass1` gives me a warning **The method doesn't override an inherited method.
Try updating this class to match the superclass, or removing the override annotation**

Comment: The only possible explanation that comes to mind is there are > 1 definitions of classes with the same name as your superclass.

Comment: the solution was hilarious , the reason is the underscore in the name of abstract method! .. should change `_abstractMethod` to `abstractMethod`. thats it! but for your record, can you explain this in an answer?

Comment: Aha, nice find! Your original question did not have the underscores. ;) No worries, you figured it out, you should get the credit!

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is an advice for whoever faces this issue:

> DON'T use a leading underscore for identifiers that aren’t private.

as [this link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#dont-use-a-leading-underscore-for-identifiers-that-arent-private) explains in dart leading underscore in an identifier to mark members and top-level declarations as private. for that it cannot be overridden within inherited classes.